# How to add a boolean toogle to a Rails index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a Rails 3.2 app, what is the best way to add a form field to an index view?

For example if I have a list of users, and want to add an "approved" button to each row to toggle a boolean field in the database.

```
#users/index.html.erb    
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Approved</th>
  </tr>
  <%= for user in @users %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
      <td><%= CHECKBOX FORM GOES HERE %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I am not sure how to set up the form tags and/or controllers to ensure that

a) the form posts to the correct location and

b) posts are sent at a point in the user flow that makes sense.

Can anyone point me towards any good examples of this sort of behavior, or suggest what I should be thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we do this is to add an observer to the checkbox and send a request to the update action or add a new action just for this feature.  The advantage of adding a new action is it's concentrated on that particular feature, no additional checks and stuff.

You will be changing/adding a few files so here it goes.  Hopefully they are easy to understand.

```
# view
<td><%= check_box_tag :approved, user.id, user.approved?, class: 'user-approve-cb' %>

# routes
resources :users do
  put :set_approved, on: :member
end

# js asset (using coffee)
$('.user-approve-cb:checkbox').change ->
  $.ajax
    url: '/users/' + @value + '/set_approved'
    type: 'PUT'
    data: { approved: $(this).attr('checked') }
    success: -> alert('User updated')

# controller
def set_approved
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  @user.update_column :approved, params[:approved]

  render nothing: true
end
```

Comment: wow, that's brilliant! I've managed to get this working using a `get` route and a `link_to "Approve" set_approved_user_path(@user, approved: true)`, but for some reason I can't get this to work with the checkbox/ put combo. I can't see any obvious reasons why. Do you have any suggestions on a methodical way to debug this?

Comment: start first by checking the parameters you get on the controller.  if you get the right parameters (true for a checked box, false otherwise) then your js is fine.  if not, start debugging your js using the console or firebug. also check the converted js if it's what you expect.

Comment: ok, I changed `data: { approved: $(this).attr('checked') }` to `data: { approved: $(this).prop('checked') }`and this is now setting the checkbox. But it will only update the attributes for the first box clicked, all subsequent are ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi jvnil, I eventually got this working. Your answer works perfectly, although I did need to change `.attr` to `.prop`. The problem with only the first box being clicked was due to a bug elsewhere in my code. Thanks for this answer!